# How can I connect a UIButton to a specific tab in my Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBarController` that has 2 tabs. Each tab is different, but both have the option to make a new post on the top. When I tap the new `post` button on either view, I have the same `ViewController` Present Modally. If I hit the `cancel` button, it dismisses and goes back to the correct tab no problem. However, if I hit the `post` button, I want it to always segue to the first tab.

How can I programmatically tell it to switch to the first tab before the

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Here is my Storyboard
[image: Storyboard]

and here is my code called when I tap the post button:

```
@IBAction func accept(sender: AnyObject) {
    var currentUserLocation = getUserLocation()
    currentUserLocation.getUserCoordinates()

    let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var tabBarController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    tabBarController.SelectedIndex = 0


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
```

I end up with the error:

```
'UITabBarController' does not have a member named 'SelectedIndex'
```

Comment: It's not `SelectedIndex = 0` but `selectedIndex = 0` with a lowcase "s"

Comment: Woooooooooooow, I cannot believe that was the problem. It worked! Thank you SO much for all your help! Really really appreciate it.

Comment: Ahaha sometimes it happens, no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following :

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var tabBarController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```

The controller at index 0 corresponds to the left-most tab, the controller at index 1 the next tab to the right, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! That seems simple enough, but I end up with an error of:

    "Cannot invoke 'setSelectedIndex' with an argument list of type '(int)'.

I think it's because I'm writing the code in a ViewController and not in the tabViewController, but I need the index to change before the dismissal...

Comment: Try by doing `setSelectedIndex(Int(index))`

Comment: I got the exact same error. When I type that line of code, "setSelectedIndex" doesn't autocomplete. I'm writing that line inside the IBAction for the button press. I'm assuming it means I can't do it there, but I don't know what to do instead...

Comment: Where you `IBAction ` is implemented ? In which controller ? Do you have access to the tabBarController in this controller ?

Comment: The IBAction is in the ViewController for the view I'm trying to dismiss. But before I dismiss it, I need to change the tab bar. I'm kinda new at this, so I can't say I know if I have access to it or not. If not, how would I go about giving it access?

Comment: Try accessing by `self.navigationController.tabBarController`

Comment: Did you implement it from the storyboard or programmatically ?

Comment: It's implemented from the storyboard. It goes into my     tabBarController, then each tab has a navigation controller, which each have a view (obviously) and they both connect to the same Post Page View. Then when dismissing the Post Page View is when I get the problem.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your storyboard to your question to find out how you can access it ?

Comment: Now I get, "UITabBarController does not have a member named 'setSelectedIndex'"

Comment: You need ton unwrap the property : `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`

Comment: Xcode gave me a warning to remove the ? when I tried to unwrap it.... and it also turned all the "as" into unwrapping "as!" But my Swift knowledge isn't extensive enough to know why that is...

Comment: Do the correction for the `as!` and the `?` Xcode is right and don't use `setSelectedIndex(0)` but `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0`

Comment: It's still giving me the "does not have member named 'setSelectedIndex'" error.... I can't see why! I found another person asking the same question but in objective C, and they gave the same answer you did! Why doesn't it work for me?!

Comment: Even when you use `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0` ? Because I have it running on my side.

Comment: Yeah! Let me show you my code. I'm updating the question